# Selector problems with dynamic content

Tags: automation, css-selectors, selector, e2e-testing, testcafe

I try to select a list item from a react generated list. TestCafe Studio will select:

```
.click(Selector('#cat_220518').find('.cl-folder-list-element-arrow'))
```

But this is a dynamic value and maybe changed with next run. So I tried to use to select text, but this fail. I use:

```
.click(Selector('span').withExactText('test1234').find('.cl-folder-list-element-arrow'))
```

The element is an arrow button that will open a list of subitems. But the click will never happen. Testcafe is waiting for the element cl-folder-list-element-arrow.
From the documentation, I read that "withExactText will select the main node of the element. To find have to work in my eyes. What is wrong with my idea?

The element on the page is:

```
<div class="category-tree-node" id="cat_220518" style="padding-left: 2%; width: 98%;">
   <div class="category-tree-node-property" draggable="true">
      <div class="cl-drop-sensors top"></div>
          <div class="cl-folder-list-element-name">
              <div class="cl-folder-list-element-arrow"></div>
                 <span>test1234</span>
          </div>
              <div class="cl-drop-sensors bottom"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The find method doesn't work because the `Selector('span').withExactText('test1234')` part of the selector returns precisely the `span` element. But if you replace 'span' with 'div', the selector should work correctly:
`Selector('div').withExactText('test123').find('.cl-folder-list-element-arrow')`

You can also make the selector safer by using the `category-tree-node` class:

`Selector('div.category-tree-node').withExactText('test1234').find('.cl-folder-list-element-arrow')`

See also: [Selector Object](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/)